# Recycler view not rendering the data list

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a recycler view in fragment using Volley library.
Data is loaded and logged successfully from the server but not displayed at all in the recycler fragment.

The request fetches the data and logs it but nothing renders in the fragment. There are no XML errors.

**HitVideoFragment.java**

```
public class HitVideoFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private HitVideoAdapter adapter;
private List<HitVideo> hitVideoList = new ArrayList<HitVideo>();


public HitVideoFragment() {
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hit_video, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //Initializing Views


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.hitvideo_recycler_view);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    adapter = new HitVideoAdapter(hitVideoList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    //Calling method to get data

    //Showing a progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this.getActivity(),"Loading Data", "Please wait...",false,false);

    //Creating a json array request
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(AppConfig.URL_HIT_VIDEOS,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Dismissing progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();

                    Log.d("Some tag", "onResponse: "+response.toString());

                    hitVideoList = new ArrayList<HitVideo>();


                    for(int i = 0; i<response.length(); i++) {
                        HitVideo hitVideo = new HitVideo();
                        JSONObject json = null;
                        try {
                            json = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            hitVideo.setTitle(json.getString("name"));
                            hitVideo.setUrl(json.getString("url"));
                            hitVideo.setUsername(json.getString("user_id"));
                            hitVideo.setHits(json.getInt("hits"));


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        hitVideoList.add(hitVideo);
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    VolleyLog.d("Hit Video", "Error: " + error.getMessage());


                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            Context _context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            SharedPreferences pref;
            String token;
            if (_context != null) {

                pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(Config.PREF_NAME, Config.PRIVATE_MODE);
                if (pref != null) {
                    token = pref.getString(Config.USER_TOKEN, null);

                    headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);


                }


            }
            return headers;
        }
    };

    //Creating request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity());

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);



}
```

This is not throwing any exceptions. And the model and adapters are doing their job fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to make `Log.d("info', adapter.getCount());` after  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and tell me how many elements do you have ther

Comment: It is returning count of 0

Comment: Are you not having any `JSONException`?

Comment: Did you add you data to adapter ??

Comment: It means that your variant with `hitVideoList.add(hitVideo);` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` is not working. try to make it like  `adapter = new HitVideoAdapter(hitVideoList); recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, true);`

Comment: I've figured it out. It was happening cause it was passing empty objects to the  `hitVideoList` I've changed the `getString` to `optString` and its working now. Thanks for the help (: @xAqweRx

Answer (score 0):

I am probably too late to this,

But I had the same issue and I fixed it by returning the list.size() on the `getItemCout()` method in the Adapter class.